# JWT signature's verification at resource-server side in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, jwt

Can I do this

1. Have one (hosted on mydomain/public) laravel Api with the 
   purpose of authenticating the user and getting a JWT token. i.e `authentication server`
2. Somehow passing this same Token to a second (hosted on
   mydomain/secure) laravel Api in order to authenticate the user and the
   access the App. i.e `resource server`

I have tried to do that using the [this](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) package. As I asked above I have done authentication on `authentication server` as described [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens) and token had been generated and I had added some data to the token that is required in resource server. And I passed that token to the `resource server` and try to parse the token I get the error like `Token has expired` 
So , my question is :

1. **How can I do verification of JWT signature's  at resource-server
   side?**
2. **Is it possible to do using JWT?**

Code I had tried to parse the token in resource server

```
Route::get("/parse/token",function(Request $request){
    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
    return $user ; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All tokens, by default, JWT mechanism save to the cache files on the `authentication server`. See config/cache.php:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
'stores' => [
    ...
    'file' => [
        'driver' => 'file',
        'path'   => storage_path('framework/cache'),
    ],
    ...
],
```

`resource server` does not have access to this files and can not parse input token.

You can try use Memcached or some Database to saving JWT Tokens.